# Disable Inline Tips that block cursor in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, popup, tooltip

**How do I disable (or offset) the annoying tips that popup over the line of Dart/Flutter code I closed in Android Studio 3.6.3?**

I would typically explore this information via the docs... so ideally I could disable them so I can easily read line I just completed / attempted to complete.

[image]

They even blocks errors I am reviewing:

[image]

To illustrate, when working on this one particular widget of text, as soon as I close the line with ',' - the above popup completely blocks the line of code I am in process reviewing.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open

> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Completion

and clear flag named `Show the parameter info popup ...`.

If you need to open this popup, use 
<kbd>Meta</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> / <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> shortcuts for `Parameter info` command.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you. What would be a practical use to keep this on? Do more experienced developers benefit from this, versus keeping a copy of the docs open to search?

Comment: The default settings should be as friendly as possible to less experienced developers, and more experienced developers will choose the best ones for themselves.